# Upload to the store issue

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, app-store

I just got this error with `CFBundleIcons.UINewsstandIcon` on the image below and I can't understand how to solve it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons in iOS7 have new sizes.

The newstand icon is only necessary if your app presents content from the Newsstand app.

Please see the App Icons section at [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

Do you want to post your info.plist ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple has updated App icon size for iOS device Version>=7. Because iOS 6 App icon different fron iOS 7 App icon. So you need to update all images which is necessary.

[iOS 7 App icon description](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html)

In Xcode 5 When you click on target of project->General -> app icons.

Here you can update all images depend upon sizes.

Answer (score 1):

icons files (diff sizes) needed to be included in the build

16, 29, 36, 40, 48, 50, 57, 58, 59, 60, 72, 75, 76, 80, 96, 100, 114, 120, 128, 144, 152.